# Place marker offset from robots position

Tags: rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently detecting an object using the Kinect and have the depth of the object. I am wanting to display this object in rviz by representing it as a simple marker.

What I am having trouble with is finding the transformed location of my robots position (with offset) to /map. i.e I want to do something like rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_footprint + (0, 1, 0) (1m Y offset).

I have gone through the tf python tutorials and have successfully set up broadcasters and listeners I am just having trouble transforming a pose given an offset of some kind. (I can successfully transform between /map and /base_footprint but I cannot add an offset to /base_footprint)

I am sure I am missing something simple, just having a bit of trouble getting this going.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269671/place-marker-offset-from-robots-position/) by [SCTaylor](https://answers.ros.org/users/31715/sctaylor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-27**:
Welcome. It would be helpful to know what you've tried so far (such as your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A static transform publisher can create a new frame relative to an another one:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 1 0 0 0 0 base_footprint base_offset 0.1
```

http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher

With that running you could then do a tf_echo with base_offset in the map frame (given a tf between map and base_footprint exists), or have a rviz Marker or Axes use the base_offset frame to visualize it.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0